# jQuery $.ajax GET cache period

Tags: ajax, caching, jquery, http-get

How long do browsers keep the cache of AJAX requests?
eg.

```
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "GetStockLevel.ashx?productId="+productId,
    success: function(data) { alert(data; }
  });
```

I don't mind if it's cached for a few minutes. But if it caches for say 30 minutes then it would be a problem.

And can we set the cache expiry? (eg. to 1 minute)

I know I can set cache to false, but I'm just curious :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could control caching by adding

```
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "Thu, 15 Apr 2010 20:00:00 GMT");
```

to your GetStockLevel.ashx handler.

If the expires header is absent, the time that the page is cached varies by browser and it is best not to depend on its behaviour.